# How check that text in quotes are lowercase text

Tags: text

**example1**:

```
test "one" hi
this is test "two" check
I need to "three" this
```

**example2**:

```
test "one" hi
this is test "Two" check
I need to "three" this
```

Is it possible to check that text (some function) in quotes (one, two, three) are lowercase text ?
In **example1** this function return true , but in **example2** this function return false;

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @phils function that return true if all text in quotes print in lowercase. Else return false. Smt like this.

Comment: Check where? Check how (interactively, by program)? What action do you mean by "check" (return a Boolean? do something else?) The question is unclear.

Comment: @Drew I updated my post

Comment: What have you tried so far to answer your own question?  What’s not working yet?

Answer (score 3):

If you use regular expressions as suggested by one of the other answers, you have to be careful to avoid checking text outside of quotes for uppercase letters. If you use just a single regular expression, you probably end up with the wrong result for

`This is a "text" with some UPPERCASE letters outside the "quoted text"`

You probably need to iterate through all the quoted text parts and check every one of them for an uppercase letter. For example:

```el
(defun check-for-uppercase-in-quotes ()
 "Return t if quoted text containing uppercase letters is found"
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((case-fold-search nil) (uppercasefound nil)) 
      (while (and (not uppercasefound) (re-search-forward "\"\\([\0-\377[:nonascii:]]*?\\)\"" nil t nil))
        (setq uppercasefound (string-match ".*[[:upper:]].*" (match-string 1))))
     uppercasefound)))
```

Edit: Modified the regular expression so that quoted text with multiple lines is correctly recognized.

Comment: Great! The one thing left to do is include `\n` to regexp to handle multiline quoted texts ;)

Comment: @muffinmad: Well spotted:) Fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

For example, you can search upper-case letters in quotes.

```el
(defun all-text-in-quotes-is-lowercase ()
  "Return t if text in quotes are lowercase text."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((case-fold-search nil))
      (not (search-forward-regexp "\".*[[:upper:]]+.*\"" nil t)))))
```